# Kubernetes Multinode CoreOS gude doesn't create ELBs in AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, amazon-elb

The [CoreOS Multinode Cluster](http://kubernetes.io/v1.1/docs/getting-started-guides/coreos/coreos_multinode_cluster.html) guide appears to have a problem. When I create a cluster and configure connectivity, everything appears fine -- however, I'm unable to create an ELB through service exposing:

```
$ kubectl expose rc my-nginx --port 80 --type=LoadBalancer
service "my-nginx" exposed

$ kubectl describe services
Name:           my-nginx
Namespace:      temp
Labels:         run=my-nginx
Selector:       run=my-nginx
Type:           LoadBalancer
IP:         10.100.6.247
Port:           <unnamed>   80/TCP
NodePort:       <unnamed>   32224/TCP
Endpoints:      10.244.37.2:80,10.244.73.2:80
Session Affinity:   None
No events.
```

The IP line that says 10.100.6.247 looks promising, but no ELB is actually created in my account. I can otherwise interact with the cluster just fine, so it seems bizarre. A "kubectl get services" listing is similar -- it shows the private IP (same as above) but the EXTERNAL_IP column is empty.

Ultimately, my goal is a solution that allows me to easily configure my VPC (ie. private subnets with NAT instances) and if I can get this working, it'd be easy enough to drop into CloudFormation since it's based on user-data. The official method of kube-up doesn't leave room for VPC-level customization in a repeatable way.

Comment: Can you confirm how you know that a load balancer is not available? The problem is that AWS does not give ELBs IP addresses, just host names. Can you try this `kubectl get svc -o yaml` and see if it returns a `hostname` attribute?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, that getting-started guide isn't nearly as up to date as the kube-up implementation. For instance, I don't see a --cloud-provider=aws flag anywhere, and the kubernetes-controller-manager would need that in order to know to call the AWS APIs.

You may want to check out the official CoreOS on AWS guide:
https://coreos.com/kubernetes/docs/latest/kubernetes-on-aws.html

If you hit a deadend or find a problem, I recommend asking in the AWS Special Interest Group forum:
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/kubernetes-sig-aws